# Always HAD high hopes or should it be always have high hopes?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

Why is that people use ''had'' instead of ''have'' when it is still happening at present.

> Example 1: the song ''High Hopes'' (by Panic At The Disco) it has a lyric line that says:
>
> ''always **had** high hopes..."
>
> Example 2: "He already **had** developed an encyclopedic knowledge of the English language"
>
> And so on...

My point here is, it is still happening at present, that, it should be ''always **have** high hopes'' and ''he already **have** developed an encyclopedic knowledge...''. Furthermore, is this an exception to the grammar rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two examples are actually different cases.

The first one is more easily understood as "[I have] always had high hopes" which means that throughout their life, their hopes have been high (relevant to the song since they are referencing the fact that in order to get into the music industry, it was their hope that kept them going). This is an implied **present perfect** tense.

If you use "**have**" in this context, it actually reads "[I] always have high hopes", which means that in their current life, they always have high hopes. (It can also be interpreted as an *imperative*, i.e. "[You should] always have high hopes")

The second case actually doesn't make sense if you replace the **had** with **have**. This become clearer if you rearrange it slightly into: "He **had** already developed an encyclopedic knowledge of the English language". This needs some more context to make sense, since this is saying that he developed this by some given time. e.g. "[By the time he was 10] he **had** already developed an encyclopedic knowledge of the English language".

While you couldn't replace it with **have**, since that implies perfect tense, you could replace it with **has**, which would make it present tense. e.g. "[Even though he is only 10] he **has** already developed an encyclopedic knowledge of the English language".

In your question you seem to think these are both examples of present tense, but they are both past tense, and so **have** is correct.